# How to check if there's a carrier signal?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm planning to develop an iphone app and I need to know if it's possible to check if the iphone has any carrier signal or if it's as "no service".

I've talked with some developers and some keep telling me that it's possible while others say that it is not possible...

Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: Why do want to check the carrier signal? I'm sure you are looking at internet availability for data connections! why not use apple reachability class?

Comment: Do you have any other reason to check the carrier signal? except for data connections?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the way MKNetworkKit handles reachability to domains. Haven't looked in depth, but I think it can tell the difference between wifi, cell network, and no service. That should give you everything you need.

https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
int wl = CTGetSignalStrength();
```